# how to get parent and children in Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to Django and I wanted to ask a simple question. let's take example model:

```py
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

with that model let's create a few objects. indentation means that the parent is specified e.g. test5 have object test3 as a parent.

- test
- test2

  - test4
- test3

  - test5

    - test6

so now my question. is there a way to get children of an object, parent of an object and nad objects without parents specified?

I've tried to work it out with filters but unfortunately, i didn't managed to figure out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you need to use select_related.
I've got the code from the django official documentation.
Below the link and the code

[Django Official documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related%60)

```
from django.db import models
```

class City(models.Model):

```
pass
```

class Person(models.Model):

```
hometown = models.ForeignKey(
    City,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
```

class Book(models.Model):

```
author = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

… then a call to Book.objects.select_related('author__hometown').get(id=4) will cache the related Person and the related City: